# How to refresh dabbrev candidates displayed by company after each save

Tags: completion, company-mode, ivy, dabbrev

I've been using Ivy Irony Company for some time and it works great on all libraries I included in my C++ program so far, but I've noticed Ivy rarely auto-completes my user defined classes, objects, variables and enumerations.

I've read about company having dabbrev backend for everything user defined in opened buffers. Also I've noticed that after I build my project with make company now displays my user defined enumerations, objects etc..

Is there a way to update dabbrev backend after each save and should I put dabbrev inside grouped backend for it to work?

As far as my init.el configuration, for autocompletion part I'm using config from https://github.com/dfrib/emacs_setup#cmake-idertags I've commented out rtags part:

```````````
(use-package irony
  :config
  (add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'irony-mode)
  (add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'irony-mode)
  (add-hook 'objc-mode-hook 'irony-mode)
  (add-hook 'irony-mode-hook 'irony-cdb-autosetup-compile-options)
  (defun my-irony-mode-hook ()
  (define-key irony-mode-map [remap completion-at-point]
    'irony-completion-at-point-async)
  (define-key irony-mode-map [remap complete-symbol]
    'irony-completion-at-point-async))
  (add-hook 'irony-mode-hook 'my-irony-mode-hook)
  (add-hook 'irony-mode-hook 'irony-cdb-autosetup-compile-options)
  )

;; Company mode.
(use-package company
  :config (global-company-mode)
  )

;; company-irony.
(use-package company-irony
  :after company
  :config (global-company-mode)
  ;; (optional) adds CC special commands to `company-begin-commands' in order to
  (add-hook 'irony-mode-hook 'company-irony-setup-begin-commands)
  )

;; Company-mode backend for C/C++ header files that works with irony-mode.
;; Complementary to company-irony by offering completion suggestions to header files.
(use-package company-irony-c-headers
  :after company-irony
  :config
  ;; Load with `irony-mode` as a grouped backend
  (eval-after-load 'company
  '(add-to-list
    'company-backends '(company-irony-c-headers company-irony)))
  )

(use-package ivy
  :config
  (ivy-mode)
  (setq ivy-use-virtual-buffers t)
  (setq enable-recursive-minibuffers t)
``````````
```````````

Comment: It's a question about Irony, I think. But you should probably file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

The dabbrev backend doesn't cache completions (so far), so you don't need to do anything for that. Except maybe start using it: your configuration snippet doesn't mention dabbrev even once.

Having said that, Irony, as a dedicated C/C++ completion backend, should provide much better results overall than dabbrev.